# browser.downloads.onChanged.addListener Doesn't work in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm having some trouble with WebExtensions in Firefox. I've got some code to track downloads, and it's working in Chrome, but not in FF.

I've boiled the code down to the minimal surface that works in Chrome but not FF:

```
function handleChanged(delta) {
    console.log(delta);
}

chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(handleChanged);
```

Whether I use *chrome.** or *browser.**, the behavior remains the same: it doesn't work. I've tried executing this line:

```
console.log(chrome.downloads.onChanged.hasListener(handleChanged));
```

After adding the listener, and it does log a value of *true*. Oddly enough, adding an *onCreated* listener works just fine:

```
function handleCreated(delta) {
    console.log(delta);
}
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(handleCreated);
```

This yields the expected object dump in the console when a download is started. Unless I'm missing something extremely obvious, I'm inclined to think this is a bug. It is not mentioned to the [incompatibilities list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities), and it is [documented by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/onChanged). The thing is, I don't see anybody else asking this question online, so I'm inclined to think a bug is unlikely and I'm messing something up.

If it helps, I'm running Firefox 51.0.1 (32-bit) on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 inside of VMWare Workstation on a Windows 7 Enterprise x64 host. I'm loading the extension using the "Load Temporary Add-on" button. It's not a problem with the core manifest or add-on itself, because three other types of listeners are working just fine. The script is running as a background script.

I appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Please detail the *exact* sequence of user interaction that is happening and the event(s) you *expect* to see. The gist of what I am currently *guessing* from your question is that you are expecting *both* a `downloads.onCreated` and a `downloads.onChanged` event to be fired when a download is created. Is that what you are saying you are expecting?

Comment: In testing, I confirmed that `downloads.onChanged` did not fire on Firefox 51.0.1 and 54.0a1 (Nightly) throughout the download of the single page I tested on each version. Chrome did fire that event multiple times during a similar process. I've not looked at the Firefox source to see when it is supposed to fire.

Comment: The interaction is start a download, wait for the download to finish. According to the documentation and the behavior seen in Chrome, the *onChanged* event should fire with a delta diffed against the original object from *onCreated*, with, at the least, a delta setting *state* to *"completed"*.

Comment: This is not firing for me either on Firefox 89